# Show facebook small login dialog in new browser window

Tags: facebook-oauth

At first is was using the Javascript SDK for facebook to authenticate my users. Now I'm  using "Facebook C# SDK".

I ahve no problems using it, but one really irritating one.

How can I get the browser to show that neat little login dialog the javascript invokes?

This is my login url

```
("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&display={2}",
```

mAppID, mRedirectUrl, "popup");

I have tried with this

```
 Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + url + "');</script>");
```

But the browser ask me for permission before I do that. THe javascript SDK opened a window without needing my permission..

How should I do to make it open a small login dialog without permission

Comment: I think I did Let me check that projects code.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out - the trick is to add `display=popup` to your oAuth URL:

```
e.g. http://www.facebook.com/login?...&display=popup
```